# PHP, mySQL, Google Maps code prints out "Array" as opposed to data value

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, google-maps

My Php/mySQL code for creating google maps markers is printing out "Array" instead of the zip codes I would like it to print. So instead of three different markers at three different locations I get three markers on Array Road in Cassville, Missouri. Here is my code

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT fldZip FROM tblLocation") 
or die(mysql_error());  

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {


print "codeAddress(\"$row\");";
}

?>
```

Can anyone help me out with this? If you need more of my code let me know, I have a feeling the error is somewhere here however.

Thanks,

Wakeeta

Comment: Whenever it echoes out array for any variable in your code, use a `print_r( $row );` statement to get info about what indexing the array uses,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`printf( "codeAddress(\"%s\")", $row['fldZip'] );`

Comment: This worked! Thank you for your help, can you explain what this does?

Comment: Well, printf() and sprintf() are useful functions from the C days. I merely used it instead of echo so that it's more readable.  Check out individual documentation for those two, but, short story is that you should have tried to print_r( $row ); to see what it looks like. mysql_fetch_array() returns -- well, an array, and to output anything you need to reference which element of the array to display.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the explanation and the help, glad to finally have this thing working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's unclear...

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

is assigning an array to the variable `$row`

So, to access individual members of the `$row` array you'll need their keys, e.g.:

`$row["fldZip"]`

Answer (score 0):

use $row['fldZip'] to retreive the value.